# Change background color if div has specific Child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

I am trying to change the background (and other styles) of a div if it has a specific child.  I am using .length to check if the specific child exists but even if it doesn't the div is taking the styles from the jquery if statement.  My HTML:

```
<div class="full-text-panel">
        <div class="main-wrap">
            <h1 class="home-h1">This is a header</h1>
            <a class="body-button">This is a button</a>
        </div><!--end main-wrap-->
    </div><!--end full-text-panel-->
```

And my jQuery:

```
            var fullText = $('.full-text-panel');
            var bodyButton = $('.body-button');

            if ( $(".full-text-panel .body-button").length > 0 ) {
                fullText.css("background", "red");
            } else {
                fullText.css("background", "blue");
            }
```

I thought this would work, but both fullText panels are taking the background red style.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you want apply blue for 'a'(element) tag only ah? not for h1

Comment: not sure what you're asking

Comment: No, I want the background of the div to be red if it has the button.  I have other divs that are the same without the button that I would like to have a blue background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your context iterate with each in jquery

```
$('.full-text-panel').each(function() {

     if($(this).find('a.body-button').length > 0){
         $(this).css("background", "red");
     }
    else{
        $(this).css("background", "blue");
      }

});
```

Comment: @user3633970 Could go the other way too, and no loop: `$('.full-text-panel').css("background", "blue"); $('a.body-button').parents('.full-text-panel').css("background", "red");`

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(function(){
  
  $('.full-text-panel:has(.body-button)').addClass('red');
  
  });
```

```css
.full-text-panel{
  background:blue;
  }

.red{
  background:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="full-text-panel">
        <div class="main-wrap">
            <h1 class="home-h1">This is a header</h1>
            <a class="body-button">This is a button</a>
        </div><!--end main-wrap-->
    </div><!--end full-text-panel-->

<div class="full-text-panel">
        <div class="main-wrap">
            <h1 class="home-h1">This is a header</h1>
        </div><!--end main-wrap-->
    </div><!--end full-text-panel-->
```